# Creating a customized 404/500 error page in Play Framework

Tags: java, playframework

How can one create global, custom looks for their 404/505 error pages using Play?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In Play Framework 1, you simply have to modify the provided `app/views/errors/404.html` and `app/views/errors/500.html` .

Comment: So - copy them to my project's folder and modify them, right?

Comment: Modifications to those files should do the trick! No need to copy them anywhere, they are already in your project.

Comment: Woops, missed them somehow ... now I see them.

Comment: Where did you find these files? When I created a new play project, I didn't find those files in my views directory?

Comment: kalvish, this is for Play 1.2.X. I guess you use 2.X?

Comment: Ugh! This is why I'm starting to HATE Play! Now I have to search all over on how to do this for 2.0.x

Answer (score 8):

Error handling changed in 2.5.x. You now need an **ErrorHandler** to handle errors and display custom error pages yourself.

The documentation for 2.5.x says:

### Supplying a custom error handler

```
import play.api.http.HttpErrorHandler
import play.api.mvc._
import play.api.mvc.Results._
import scala.concurrent._
import javax.inject.Singleton;

@Singleton
class ErrorHandler extends HttpErrorHandler {

  def onClientError(request: RequestHeader, statusCode: Int, message: String) = {
    Future.successful(
      Status(statusCode)("A client error occurred: " + message)
    )
  }

  def onServerError(request: RequestHeader, exception: Throwable) = {
    Future.successful(
      InternalServerError("A server error occurred: " + exception.getMessage)
    )
  }
}
```

You can find the default error pages on Github: https://github.com/playframework/playframework/tree/master/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/views/defaultpages

See https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaErrorHandling for more detail.

Answer (score 4):

In documentation for 2.3.x:

## Providing an application error page

When an exception occurs in your application, the onError operation will be called. The default is to use the internal framework error page:

```
import play.api._
import play.api.mvc._
import play.api.mvc.Results._
import scala.concurrent.Future

object Global extends GlobalSettings {

  override def onError(request: RequestHeader, ex: Throwable) = {
    Future.successful(InternalServerError(
      views.html.errorPage(ex)
    ))
  }

}
```

Source: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaGlobal#Providing-an-application-error-page

### Not found (404) error page

You'll need a `onHandlerNotFound` handler alongside the above `onError` handler:

```
override def onHandlerNotFound(request: RequestHeader) = {
  Future.successful(NotFound(views.html.errors.notFoundPage()))
}
```

Source: this is not documented but have a look in the `GlobalSettings` trait definition.

## Default error page template source

The source for the default error template in production for 2.3.x can be read here:

https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/2.3.x/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/views/defaultpages/error.scala.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use this :

```
import javax.inject.{Inject, Singleton}
import play.api.http.DefaultHttpErrorHandler
import play.api.mvc.Results._
import play.api.mvc.{RequestHeader, Result}

import scala.concurrent.{ExecutionContext, Future}

@Singleton
class ErrorHandler @Inject()(implicit executionContext:ExecutionContext) extends   DefaultHttpErrorHandler{



override def onServerError(request: RequestHeader, exception: Throwable): Future[Result] = {
exception match {
  case e:scala.MatchError => Future(Ok("Page Not Found"))
  case _ => Future(Ok("Internal Server Error :("))

}

}


}
```