# Scala Play Framework, How to handle unknown url

Tags: scala, playframework, routes

Hey i am working on scala play framework, what i need to do is, when someone enter some `random(unknown) url`, that is not defined in routes file, they need to be routed to the some another not found page, with `404 page not found http header response`. instead of displaying the whole routes file as error.

using sbt : `sbt launcher version 0.13.8`

using scala : `scalaVersion := "2.11.6"`
using play framework 2x

[image: Action not found]

Comment: Which version of play framework are you using?

Comment: @Tyth sbt launcher version 0.13.8

Comment: @Tyth scalaVersion := "2.11.6"

Comment: Look at the 2nd answer for play 2.3 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8871143/creating-a-customized-404-500-error-page-in-play-framework

Comment: The routes are only displayed when you're running in development mode.

Comment: look at https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/ScalaGlobal

Answer (score 1):

You can override these in your `Global.scala / Global.java` file. For Java the could look similar to this:

```
public F.Promise<Result> onHandlerNotFound(Http.RequestHeader request) {
    return F.Promise.<Result>pure(notFound(
            Messages.get("error.routeNotFound")
    ));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are looking for Scala code for `Global.scala` to display your own 404 Page.

`Global.scala` should be under your `/views` folder. And override the `onHandlerNotFound` method in it, like this:

```
override def onHandlerNotFound(request: RequestHeader) = {
  var cookies: Seq[Cookie] = Seq()
  Future.successful(NotFound("hello world!!!!").withCookies(cookies:_*))
}
```

The `NotFound` is a `PageCtrl.Status` method which may need a import at the top of `Global.scala`. You can try using `NotFound("Hello World")` to see what's happening. It will display pure text `"hello world"` instead of default 404 page.

So the final code should be like

```
override def onHandlerNotFound(request: RequestHeader) = {
  var cookies: Seq[Cookie] = Seq()
  Future.successful(NotFound(view.html.yourOwn404PageHtml).withCookies(cookies:_*))
}
```

The `withCookies` is just used to create a `Result` object. You can use other method belongs to `NotFound()`.

Answer (score 0):

In Play2.6 you can handle unknown/broken API call buy using below code.

```
import javax.inject._
import models.Response
import play.api._
import play.api.http.DefaultHttpErrorHandler
import play.api.libs.json.Json
import play.api.mvc.Results._
import play.api.mvc._
import play.api.routing.Router
import _root_.controllers.JSONHelper.ResponseWrites

import scala.concurrent._

class ErrorHandler @Inject()(env: Environment,
                              config: Configuration,
                              sourceMapper: OptionalSourceMapper,
                              router: Provider[Router])
  extends DefaultHttpErrorHandler(env, config, sourceMapper, router) {

  override protected def onNotFound(request: RequestHeader, message: String): Future[Result] = {
    Future.successful(
      NotFound(Json.toJson(Response(isSuccess = false,"Resource Not Found", ("", ""))))
    )
  }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use customized ErrorHandler to return a json format error message, status result with status code or blank page instead.

```
package errors

import play.api.http.HttpErrorHandler
import play.api.mvc._
import play.api.mvc.Results._
import scala.concurrent._
import javax.inject.Singleton

@Singleton
class MyErrorHandler extends HttpErrorHandler {

  def onClientError(request: RequestHeader, statusCode: Int, message: String) = {
    Future.successful(
      Ok() // Replace with your error handle here
    )
  }

  def onServerError(request: RequestHeader, exception: Throwable) = ???
}
```

In application.conf

```
play.http.errorHandler = "errors.MyErrorHandler"
```

You can find detail on playframework document.
https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaErrorHandling

Comment: While this might be a valuable hint to solve the problem, a good answer also demonstrates the solution.  Please [edit] to provide example code to show what you mean. Alternatively, consider writing this as a comment instead.