# How to redirect to error page, If the URL is invalid?

Tags: scala, playframework, routes, custom-error-pages

I am beginner to play scala framework. And I have created simple CRUD operation using it.
In my routes file I have declared all the necesary urls for different actions.
I want to know if user input some wrong url path from browser How should I display error page in play scala? Right now I am getting all the routes which are already defined.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Scala Play Framework, How to handle unknown url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32350149/scala-play-framework-how-to-handle-unknown-url)

Comment: I am using play 2.8.x version. The url which you provided there was a globalSetting defined. And in my play project there is not any such type of object defined. If it is user defined then how to do this.

Answer (score 3):

I just found a solution for it

https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/ScalaErrorHandling

this is the latest play scala documentation which handles such type of condition.
Since I am using runtime dependency injection (e.g. Guice), the error handler can be dynamically loaded at runtime.
The simplest way is to create a class in the root package called ErrorHandler that implements HttpErrorHandler.
If you place your error handler in the root package (i.e. package-less) and name it ErrorHandler, Play will use it by default.

But, in case you want to:

- Add it inside a package;
- Configure different error handlers for different environments;

Then add in application.conf the configuration property play.http.errorHandler pointing to your custom error handler class:

```
play.http.errorHandler = "com.example.ErrorHandler"
```