# Play framework 2.x, disable HTML error pages?

Tags: scala, http, playframework

How can I disable the default HTML pages that Play sends back as error? 
In my app I don't care about the browser and would just like to receive a HTTP failing status and message. Thanks.

Comment: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaErrorHandling

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating a customized 404/500 error page in Play Framework](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8871143/creating-a-customized-404-500-error-page-in-play-framework)